Error running downloaded vs_installer.exe on Windows: "This app can't run on your PC"
I have successfully downloaded Visual Studio Installer using curl with the following command:
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -o vs_installer.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_installer.exe

However, when I attempt to run vs_installer.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --includeRecommended --passive, I encounter an error message stating:
This app can't run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.




I am unsure how to resolve this issue and would appreciate any guidance. Has anyone else encountered this problem or knows what might be causing it? My goal is to install the Visual Studio Community from the cmd command line.

Tell us about your PC. Is it Windows 10? Windows 11? 32-bit vs 64? Maybe running one of the odd new snapdragon Arm systems? Is it in S mode? And fwiw, when I check that url I'm redirected to Bing instead of getting an installer file. So maybe your shortcut is out of date.

My bad. It is Windows 10, 64 bit, x86

You can follow Use command-line parameters to install, update, and manage Visual Studio  to install Visual Studio.

It looks like the url is invalid due to 0KB Size.
https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_installer.exe


If you want to install the Visual Studio Community from the cmd command line, you can follow steps below:
1.Download Visual Studio Installer  using cur.
https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_community.exe

C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -o vs_community.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_community.exe

2.Install Visual Studio via command-line parameters.
vs_community.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --includeRecommended --passive

For more information, please refer to doc:
Use command-line parameters to install Visual Studio

I think the problem is with C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe. I got the same error again. But when I download the file manually from the website it seems OK.

Glad to hear that you are able to install visual studio. Happy coding

Yes, looks like the issue with curl command. Please run the following command curl -o vs_community.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_community.exe and it will download the file successfully.

The issue is likely caused by the downloaded file being incomplete or corrupted due to a redirect in the URL. To resolve this, use the -L option with curl to follow redirects:
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -L -o vs_community.exe https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_community.exe

This should download the complete installer file, allowing you to run it without the "This app can't run on your PC" error. After downloading, one can proceed with the original command to install Visual Studio Community.

Bonus point: If you want to install an older version you can do it with
vs_community.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --includeRecommended --passive --channelUri https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel


That's right. By default, curl does not follow HTTP redirects, but using the -L option tells curl to follow any Location headers that the server sends back.
